# How do I sort an object with children properties?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that represents a tree:

```
const obj = {
  "1": {
    id: "1",
    children: ["1-1", "1-2"]
  },
  "1-1": {
    id: "1-1",
    children: ["1-1-1", "1-1-2"]
  },
  "1-2": {
    id: "1-2",
    children: []
  },
  "1-1-1": {
    id: "1-1-1",
    children: []
  },
  "1-1-2": {
    id: "1-1-2",
    children: []
  }
};
```

The result is a list similar to:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    1
    <ul>
      <li>
        1.1
        <ul>
          <li>1.1.1</li>
          <li>1.1.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        1.2
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I need is to transform the object above to an array where items go in the order they do in the list representation, i.e. `['1', '1-1', '1-1-1', '1-1-2', '1-2']`. Ids can be any so I can't rely on them. It's the order of items in the `children` property that matters.

### Update

The final result should be `['1', '1-1', '1-1-1', '1-1-2', '1-2']` i.e. the order they come in the list from the top to the bottom.

Comment: could you show us what you've tried please ?

Comment: @jonatjano, ugh it's a thousand variations of broken recursion functions that return either undefined or console errors. Not sure if this would help.

Comment: This is a Breadth First or Level Order Traversal in your **obj** variable. You can save it to a tree. From then on it would be easy to print it in any other way.

Comment: giving broken version, the one which is the closest, allow us to show you what you didn't think of, it's allow you to learn from your errors instead of only getting a valid snippets

Comment: The output which you expect is not clear . Do you want only children items in the output or ids should be present in the output array?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi, the output should be the order they come in the list, i.e. `['1', '1-1', '1-1-1', '1-1-2', '1-2']`.

Comment: @jonatjano, thanks I know the rules. However, none of my attempts returned anything even close to what I need.

Comment: Is there a limit to the depth or will `"1-1-1"` also have children `"1-1-1": { id: "1-1-1", children: ["1-1-1-1", ...]}`

Comment: the order they come in list is NOT this => `['1', '1-1', '1-1-1', '1-1-2', '1-2']`  are you sure its  not `["1", "1-1", "1-2", "1-1-1", "1-1-2"]`

Comment: @pilchard the nesting level can be any.

Comment: @jonatjano Getting valid snippets are often more useful for future readers than fixing coding issues. It will only distract from the actual goal of the question. As long as the question is clear, answerable and properly scoped, there is no value in adding these attempts.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, I am talking about the visual representation from top to bottom, please run the code snippet I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use DFS to parse. It can sort any depth data. (You can try the obj2)

```js
const obj = {
  "1": {
    id: "1",
    children: ["1-1", "1-2"]
  },
  "1-1": {
    id: "1-1",
    children: ["1-1-1", "1-1-2"]
  },
  "1-2": {
    id: "1-2",
    children: []
  },
  "1-1-1": {
    id: "1-1-1",
    children: []
  },
  "1-1-2": {
    id: "1-1-2",
    children: []
  }
};

const obj2 = {
  "2": {
    id: "2",
    children: ["2-1", "2-2", "2-3"]
  },
  "2-1": {
    id: "2-1",
    children: ["2-1-1", "2-1-2"]
  },
  "2-2": {
    id: "2-2",
    children: []
  },
  "2-3": {
    id: "2-3",
    children: []
  },
  "2-1-1": {
    id: "2-1-1",
    children: ["2-1-1-1", "2-1-1-2"]
  },
  "2-1-2": {
    id: "2-1-2",
    children: ["2-1-2-1"]
  },
  "2-1-1-1": {
    id: "2-1-1-1",
    children: []
  },
  "2-1-1-2": {
    id: "2-1-1-2",
    children: []
  },
  "2-1-2-1": {
    id: "2-1-2-1",
    children: []
  },
};

/* DFS */
function sort(id) {
  if (!sorted.includes(id)) {
    sorted.push(id);
    obj[id].children.forEach(sub => {
      sort(sub);
    });
  }
}

/* MAIN */

let sorted = [];

for (let [id, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  sort(id);
}

console.log(sorted.flat());
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I will give it a try for sure.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj={1:{id:"1",children:["1-1","1-2"]},"1-1":{id:"1-1",children:["1-1-1","1-1-2"]},"1-2":{id:"1-2",children:[]},"1-1-1":{id:"1-1-1",children:[]},"1-1-2":{id:"1-1-2",children:[]}};

const output = Object.keys(obj)
// remove every non root
Object.entries(obj).forEach(el => el[1].children.forEach(child => {
  let index = output.indexOf(child)
  if (index !== -1) {
    output.splice(index, 1)
  }
}))

for (let i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
  // for each get it's children
  let children = obj[output[i]].children
  // push them just behind it
  output.splice(i + 1, 0, ...children)
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: The result should be `['1', '1-1', '1-1-1', '1-1-2', '1-2']` (the order they come in the list representation). So this is a wrong answer, unfortunately. Thanks for trying!

Comment: I read that wrong, I'll try again (btw my order is good but not the way I got it)

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a recursive call with the base condition to ignore the traversed node

```js
const obj = {
  "1": {
    id: "1",
    children: ["1-1", "1-2"],
  },
  "1-1": {
    id: "1-1",
    children: ["1-1-1", "1-1-2"],
  },
  "1-2": {
    id: "1-2",
    children: [],
  },
  "1-1-1": {
    id: "1-1-1",
    children: [],
  },
  "1-1-2": {
    id: "1-1-2",
    children: [],
  },
}

function traverse(obj) {
  const res = []
  const traversed = {}

  function getChildren(id) {
    if (traversed[id]) {
      return
    }
    res.push(id)
    traversed[id] = true
    obj[id].children.forEach((childId) => getChildren(childId))
  }

  for (const id in obj) {
    getChildren(id)
  }

  return res
}

console.log(traverse(obj))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will definitely try this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are expecting ?

```
  let ans = []
  function recursiveCallObj(key){
    !ans.includes(key) ? ans.push(key)  : ""
    for(let i=0; i< obj[key].children.length; i++){
      if(!ans.includes(obj[key].children[i])){
        recursiveCallObj(obj[key].children[i])
      }
      else{
        return
      }
    }
  }
  for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)){
    if(value.children.length > 0){
      recursiveCallObj(key)
    }
    else{
      !ans.includes(key) ? ans.push(key)  : ""
    }
  }
  console.log(ans)
```